# Percentual de Juros sobre Price

Tags: genexus, matemática

Tudo bem?

Estou com dificuldade para encontrar o **percentual de juros** de um parcelamento (*leia financiamento*), sabendo alguns valores finais. Dada a seguinte fórmula:

```
pmt = (PV.i) / (1 / (1 - (1+i)^n) )
```

Esta é fórmula padrão Price, para se descobri o valor da parcela. Os valores que eu tenho são:

```
pmt = 61,45

PV = 234,00

n = 4
```

Eu preciso descobri o valor de **i - percentual de juros**. Já procurei bastante na net, mas como sou leigo em matemática financeira, não localizei nada que me ajude.

Informação: para estes valores, eu sei que o **percentual de juros** é igual a **0,02**, ou **2%**, entretanto eu necessito de uma fórmula que eu possa aplicar em outros valores, e com isso obter o valor de **i**.

Comment: vc quer aplicar esse calculo em alguma linguagem de programação especifica?

Comment: Sim, preciso aplicar isso em Genexus, versão 9. Mas se eu tiver a fórmula, não farei implicação com a linguagem. Caso você tiver um exemplo em alguma linguagem de programação, e puder me passar, eu agradeço, pois assim terei mais material para analisar.

Comment: Se você quer resolver seu problema em alguma linguagem especifica ou algo parecido, você deve [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/150638/edit) e  colocar isso na sua pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade eu desejo uma solução para a fórmula, especificamente. O programa - linguagem de programação - será afetado por isso, mas pra mim não adiantará um programa que me traga um resultado, se eu não consigo explicar, ou entender como este resultado é calculado - talvez esse não seja o melhor argumento, mas podemos tomá-lo como exemplo. Vou aguardar um pouco, e ver se alguém consegue me responder sobre a fórmula, caso eu não obtiver um retorno objetivo, seguirei vosso conselho. Agradeço pela orientação ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível isolar a taxa de juros ("i") nesta fórmula. É preciso achar a taxa de juros usando interpolação linear ou o método da bisecção. O método da bisecção funciona mais ou menos assim:

```
i_minimo = 0
i_maximo = 100%

faça enquanto verdadeiro:
    pmt_minimo = formula_pmt(i_minimo)
    pmt_medio = formula_pmt((i_minimo + i_maximo) / 2)
    pmt_maximo = formula_pmt(i_maximo)
    if pmt < pmt_minimo || pmt > pmt_maximo:
        retorna erro
    diferenca = pmt_medio - pmt

    if abs(diferenca) < 0.00001: # aqui você escolhe a precisão desejada
        return i_medio

    if diferenca < 0:
        pmt_minimo = pmt_medio
    else if diferenca > 0:
        pmt_maximo = pmt_medio
```

Comment: agradeço pelo retorno! Eu já havia chegado numa solução similar. Junto com uns colegas meus chegamos a apelidar esse "método" de "força bruta", pois ficar tentando um percentual até que o mesmo dê o resultado igual, ou muito próximo. Como comentei, sou leigo em matemática financeira, por isso estou busquei uma forma de fugir desta solução, mas acredito que esta seja a única possível. Apenas por curiosidade, você saberia me explicar o motivo pelo qual não é possível isolar o ("i") desta fórmula?

Comment: A solução é eficiente porque resolve um bit do resultado a cada ciclo. Um número de ponto flutuante duplo tem 56 bits de precisão, mas talvez você nem precise disso tudo. É possível que interpolação linear seja mais eficiente, só que dependendo da fórmula financeira o "i" pode ter duas soluções e aí a interpolação se atrapalha. Realmente não sei o motivo matemático exato por que o "i" não pode ser isolado; coloquialmente falando é porque ele aparece duas vezes no lado direito e em uma delas está dentro de uma função não-aritmética (a potência).